# Print a Given Number in Reverse

Tags: javascript

My instructor gave this code that works well and, for where we are at this point in the course, this is the code he expects us to use. I understand 90% of this, but not fully sure why combining %10, math.trunc, and then multiplying by 10 will give me the reverse number. I really hope there is someone here that can explain it in simple terms for me to understand. Thank you!!

```
let num = +prompt("enter number");
let reversedNum = 0;
while (num !=0){
    let rightMostDigit = num %10;
    num = Math.trunc(num / 10);
    reversedNum = reversedNum*10 + rightMostDigit;
}

document.write(reversedNum)
```

Comment: Pick a number for `num` and for each line of your code, write down in a paper the values of each variable. This will help you to understanding the code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure I understand how math.trunc (x/10) works. I was hoping someone can explain that in the context of the code and in general. Thank you.

Comment: `a/b` real-divides `a` with `b`, so `4/2 === 2` and `5/2 === 2.5`. `Math.trunc` removes the decimal place for positive numbers, so `Math.trunc(2) === 2` and `Math.trunc(2.5) === 2`. That said, take 123 for example. Dividing it by 10 (12.3) and removing the decimal place leaves us with 12, which is 123 without the last digit. Basically, `Math.trunc(x/10)` returns `x` without the last digit.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Thanks! So, now the only thing I don't understand is how the last line of code in turn puts the number in reverse :/